# Get relationship between nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have this following type of graph which I get using this query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:REPORTS_TO *]->(c:Person) WHERE p.name="F"
WITH COLLECT (c) + p AS all 
UNWIND all as p MATCH (p)-[:REPORTS_TO]-(c) 
RETURN p,c;
```

[image]

**Use-Case:**

**1. I want to find what level is a node at with respect to node `F`?**
Example :

```
    Node `D`, `E` are direct child of `F`, hence they are at level 1
    
    Node `A,B,C` are childs of `D` (which is child of `F`) hence level 2
    
    Node `X` is child of `A' (which is at level 2), hence level 3

and so onnnnn....
```

I tried to solve this by introducing a variable `i` and increment it with each iteration (**but it didn't worked**).

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:REPORTS_TO *]->(c:Person) WHERE p.name="F"
WITH COLLECT (c) + p AS all ,i:int=0
UNWIND all as p MATCH (p)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(c) 
RETURN p,c, i=i+1;
```

**2. Given two nodes find relation between then**

e.g `Find relation between F and X?`

Expected `answer = 3 (as it is at level 3)`

**How should I proceed to solve these use-cases?**

Note : **Graphical response from Neo4j server isn't necessarily needed , Json response will also be fine.**

Answer (score 2):

UC1 Use [Path](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-path-variables) and `length(p)` function

```
MATCH p=(root:Person)-[:REPORTS_TO *]->(child:Person) 
WHERE root.name="F"
RETURN nodes(p)[-2], nodes(p)[-1],length(p)
```

This will find all paths from root node, and return pairs of second to last and last nodes + level you want.

nodes(p) - list of nodes on path p

[-2] - second node from the end of the list

UC2: use `shortestPath` function:

```
MATCH (p1:Person),(p2:Person)
WHERE p1.name = '..' AND p2.name = '...'
MATCH p=shortestPath((p2)-[:REPORTS_TO*]->(p2))
RETURN length(p)
```

Comment: Many thanks solved `use-case 1` , but how to proceed for `use-case 2`

Comment: @PrakashPandey added answer to uc2